# Can't insert data into Room Database

Tags: android, database, kotlin, android-room, sql-insert

Hi guys i have a problem about inserting data to Database using Room
i have try so many things, but it's not working, maybe you can help me out to solve this problem

the problem is i want to insert the data when i click FAB button using setOnClickListener

```
binding.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener {
            val userId = item
            if (userId != null) {
                viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                    if (viewModel.isFavorite.value == true) {
                        viewModel.delete(userId)
                        Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "User dengan ID $userId dihapus dari favorit.")
                    } else {
                        viewModel.insert(userId)
                        Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "User dengan ID $userId ditambah ke favorit.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

inside setOnClickListener i check the user ID, if the ID is not in the the DB i will send the data using insert function, if the data is in DB i will delete the data using delete function, but the thing is the data cannot be inserted or deleted from DB, i have check the app inspector but the data doesn't show up, there is an error in Log Cat that i don't understand what is the meaning is that, here is the error :

```
 E  Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
 E  RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
E Couldn't load memtrack module
```

note : my connection is fine so i don't think the error is from my connection

here is my code:

// DetailUserActivit.kt

```
    package com.example.projectone.userdetail

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.activity.viewModels
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
    import androidx.core.view.isVisible
    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
    import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
    import coil.load
    import coil.transform.CircleCropTransformation
    import com.example.project_one.R
    import com.example.project_one.databinding.ActivityDetailUserBinding
    import com.example.projectone.data.model.ResponseDetailUserGithub
    import com.example.projectone.data.model.ResponseUserGithub
    import com.example.projectone.userdetail.fragment.UserFollower
    import com.example.projectone.utils.ResultViewModel
    import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayoutMediator
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
    import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext


    class DetailUserActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailUserBinding
        private val viewModel by viewModels<DetailUserViewModel>{
            DetailViewModelFactory(application)
        }

        private var isFavorite = false


        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityDetailUserBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

            val item = intent.getParcelableExtra<ResponseUserGithub.Item>("userItems")
            val username = item?.login ?: "User Not Found"

            viewModel.resultDetailUser.observe(this) {
                when(it) {
                    is ResultViewModel.Success<*> -> {
                        val user = it.data as ResponseDetailUserGithub
                        binding.imageUser.load(user.avatar_url) {
                            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
                        }

                        binding.fullNames.text = user.name
                        binding.username.text = user.login
                        binding.followerCount.text = user.followers.toString()
                        binding.followingCount.text = user.following.toString()
                        binding.repositoryCount.text = user.public_repos.toString()


                    }
                    is ResultViewModel.Error -> {
                        Toast.makeText(this, it.exception.message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                    is ResultViewModel.Loading -> {
                        binding.progressBar.isVisible = it.isLoading
                    }
                }
            }

            viewModel.getUser(username)
            val fragments = mutableListOf<Fragment>(
                UserFollower.newInstance(UserFollower.FOLLOWERS),
                UserFollower.newInstance(UserFollower.FOLLOWING)
            )
            val titleTabFragments = mutableListOf(
                getString(R.string.follower_tab), getString(R.string.following_tab)
            )
            val adapter = DetailUserAdapter(this, fragments)
            binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter

            TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) {tab, position ->
                tab.text = titleTabFragments[position]
            }.attach()

            binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object: TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
                override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                    if (tab?.position == 0) {
                        viewModel.getFollowerUser(username)
                    } else {
                        viewModel.getFollowingUser(username)
                    }
                }

                override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }

                override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                }

            })
            viewModel.getFollowerUser(username)

            viewModel.resultFavoriteAdd.observe(this) {
                updateFavoriteButtonColor(true)
            }
            viewModel.resultFavoriteDelete.observe(this) {
                updateFavoriteButtonColor(false)
            }

            viewModel.isFavorite.observe(this) { isFavoriteValue ->
                updateFavoriteButtonColor(isFavoriteValue)
            }


            binding.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener {
                val userId = item
                if (userId != null) {
                    viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
                        // Cek status isFavorite berdasarkan status saat ini
                        if (isFavorite) {
                            // Jika sebelumnya adalah favorit, hapus dari database

                                viewModel.delete(userId)

                            // Perbarui status isFavorite dan tombol favorit
                            isFavorite = false
                            updateFavoriteButtonColor(false)
                            Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "User dengan ID $userId dihapus dari favorit.")
                        } else {
                            // Jika sebelumnya tidak favorit, tambahkan ke database

                                viewModel.insert(userId)

                            // Perbarui status isFavorite dan tombol favorit
                            isFavorite = true
                            updateFavoriteButtonColor(true)
                            Log.d("DetailUserActivity", "User dengan ID $userId ditambahkan ke favorit.")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }



        }



        private fun updateFavoriteButtonColor(isFavorite: Boolean) {
            val colorRes = if (isFavorite) R.color.lavender else android.R.color.white
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorRes)
            binding.favoriteButton.setColorFilter(color)
        }


        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            when(item.itemId) {
                android.R.id.home -> {
                    finish()
                }
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

// DetailViewModel.kt

```
    import android.app.Application
    import android.util.Log
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
    import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
    import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
    import com.example.projectone.data.db.FavDao
    import com.example.projectone.data.model.ResponseUserGithub
    import com.example.projectone.data.repo.FavoriteRepository
    import com.example.projectone.data.service.ApiClient
    import com.example.projectone.utils.ResultViewModel
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onCompletion
    import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.onStart
    import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

    class DetailUserViewModel(application: Application) : ViewModel() {
        val resultDetailUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFollowersUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFollowingUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFavoriteAdd = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFavoriteDelete = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val resultFavoriteCheck = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()

        val myGithubDetail = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val myFollowerUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()
        val myFollowingUser = MutableLiveData<ResultViewModel>()


        private val mFavRepo: FavoriteRepository = FavoriteRepository(application)

        private val _isFavorite = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
        val isFavorite: LiveData<Boolean> = _isFavorite
        
        suspend fun insert(fav: ResponseUserGithub.Item) {
                if (_isFavorite.value != null) {
                    if (_isFavorite.value == true) {
                            mFavRepo.insert(fav)
                            resultFavoriteAdd.value = ResultViewModel.Success(true)
                    }
                }

            _isFavorite.value = _isFavorite.value != true
        }

        suspend fun delete(fav: ResponseUserGithub.Item) {
                if (_isFavorite.value != null) {
                    if (_isFavorite.value == true) {
                        mFavRepo.delete(fav)
                        resultFavoriteDelete.value = ResultViewModel.Success(true)
                    }
                }

            _isFavorite.value = _isFavorite.value != true
        }

        fun findById(id: Int) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                val isFavoriteValue = mFavRepo.findById(id) != null
                _isFavorite.postValue(isFavoriteValue)
            }
        }


        fun getUser(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = ApiClient
                        .githubService
                        .getDetailUserFromGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    resultDetailUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getFollowerUser(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = ApiClient
                        .githubService
                        .getFollowerUserFromGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    resultFollowersUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getFollowingUser(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = ApiClient
                        .githubService
                        .getFollowingUserFromGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    resultFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getMyGithub(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = ApiClient
                        .githubService
                        .getMyGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    myGithubDetail.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    myGithubDetail.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    myGithubDetail.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    myGithubDetail.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getMyFollower(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = ApiClient
                        .githubService
                        .getMyFollowerGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    myFollowerUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    myFollowerUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    myFollowerUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    myFollowerUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }

        fun getMyFollowing(username: String) {
            viewModelScope.launch {
                flow {
                    val response = ApiClient
                        .githubService
                        .getMyFollowingGithub(username)
                    emit(response)
                } .onStart {
                    myFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(true)
                } .onCompletion {
                    myFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Loading(false)
                } .catch {
                    Log.e("Error ", it.message.toString())
                    it.printStackTrace()
                    myFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Error(it)
                } .collect {
                    // Ubah tipe data yang dikirimkan ke resultSuccess.value
                    myFollowingUser.value = ResultViewModel.Success(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class DetailViewModelFactory(private val application: Application) : ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory() {
        override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(DetailUserViewModel::class.java)) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                return DetailUserViewModel(application) as T
            }
            throw IllegalAccessException("Unkwon ViewModel :" + modelClass.name)
        }
    }
```

// FavoriteRepository.kt

```
    import android.app.Application
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import com.example.projectone.data.db.FavDao
    import com.example.projectone.data.db.FavDb
    import com.example.projectone.data.model.ResponseUserGithub
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
    import kotlinx.coroutines.withContext
    import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
    import java.util.concurrent.Executors

    class FavoriteRepository( application: Application) {


        private val mFavDao: FavDao
        private val executorService: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
        init {
            val db = FavDb.getDatabase(application)
            mFavDao = db.FavDao()
        }
        fun getAllFavUser(): LiveData<MutableList<ResponseUserGithub.Item>> = mFavDao.loadAll()
        fun insert(fav: ResponseUserGithub.Item) {
            executorService.execute { mFavDao.insertFav(fav) }
        }
        fun delete(fav: ResponseUserGithub.Item) {
            executorService.execute { mFavDao.deleteFav(fav) }
        }

        fun findById(id: Int): LiveData<ResponseUserGithub.Item?> {
            return mFavDao.findByid(id)
        }


    }
```

// FavDao.kt

```
    import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
    import androidx.room.Dao
    import androidx.room.Delete
    import androidx.room.Insert
    import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy
    import androidx.room.Query
    import com.example.projectone.data.model.ResponseUserGithub

    @Dao
    interface FavDao {
        @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
        fun insertFav(user: ResponseUserGithub.Item)

        @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
        fun loadAll(): LiveData<MutableList<ResponseUserGithub.Item>>

        @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id LIKE :id LIMIT 1")
        fun findByid(id: Int): LiveData<ResponseUserGithub.Item?>

        @Delete
        fun deleteFav(user: ResponseUserGithub.Item)=
    }
```

// FavDb.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.projectone.data.model.ResponseUserGithub

@Database(entities = [ResponseUserGithub.Item::class], version = 1)
abstract class FavDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun FavDao(): FavDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: FavDb? = null
        @JvmStatic
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): FavDb {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(FavDb::class.java) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        FavDb::class.java, "fav_database")
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE as FavDb
        }
    }
}
```

// ResponseUseGithub.kt

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

data class ResponseUserGithub(
    val incomplete_results: Boolean,
    val items: List<Item>,
    val total_count: Int
) {
    @Parcelize
    @Entity(tableName = "user")
    data class Item(
        @ColumnInfo(name = "avatar_url")
        val avatar_url: String,
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: Int,
        @ColumnInfo(name = "login")
        val login: String
    ) : Parcelable

}
```

Maybe you can help me and teach me how to fix this problem

Comment: I think you'll need to be more clear. "Not working" could mean a hundred different things and that's a lot of code to go through without knowing what we are even looking for.

Comment: ouh sorry, i'll fix the detail

Comment: hey I have fixed it, you can check it again my question, i hope it can explain the problem more clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to determine where a problem is, it is often best to minimise the location. You have a lot of code and the problem could be in numerous (at a guess likely due to running of the main thread (which is what is recommended)).

So you can quite easily split the issue into two parts:-

1. Is the issue with actually accessing the database (inserting and deleting data), or
2. Is the issue with retrieving the data that is running off the main thread by the main thread.

The first can quite easily be established with a few code changes that inserts and deletes on the main thread. If these work then the issue is with 2.

So if you:-

1. Temporarily add `.allowMainThreadQueries` to the methods invoked by the dataBaseBuilder, the database access can use on the main thread.

   1. Obviously remove this when the issue has been resolved.
2. Temporarily change the `@Dao` functions so they do use LiveData, e.g. use `fun loadAll(): /*LiveData<*/MutableList<ResponseUserGithub.Item>/*>*/`
3. Change or add activity code that will utilise the main thread, e.g. to demonstrate/show that the database code is fine. The following Activity code has been used

:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: FavDb
    lateinit var dao: FavDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = FavDb.getDatabase(this)
        dao = db.FavDao()

        dao.insertFav(ResponseUserGithub.Item("avatarURL001",0,"loginA"))
        dao.insertFav(ResponseUserGithub.Item("avatarURL002",1,"loginB"))
        dao.insertFav(ResponseUserGithub.Item("avatarURL003",2,"loginC"))
        dao.insertFav(ResponseUserGithub.Item("avatarURL004",-99,"loginD"))
        logStuff("STG001")
        val rowsDeleted = dao.deleteFav(ResponseUserGithub.Item("not an avatarURL????",1,"not a loginZ"))
        logStuff("STG002_DLT${rowsDeleted}")

    }

    fun logStuff(tagSuffix: String) {
        for (i in dao.loadAll()) {
            Log.d("ITEMINFO_${tagSuffix}","Item avatarURL is ${i.avatar_url} Login is ${i.login} ID is ${i.id}")
        }
    }
}
```

This in addition to the temporary changes made for 1 and 2 which result in:-

```
@Dao
interface FavDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertFav(user: ResponseUserGithub.Item)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    fun loadAll(): /*LiveData<*/MutableList<ResponseUserGithub.Item>/*>*/

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id LIKE :id LIMIT 1")
    fun findByid(id: Int): LiveData<ResponseUserGithub.Item?>

    @Delete
    fun deleteFav(user: ResponseUserGithub.Item)/*= ????? */: Int
}

@Database(entities = [ResponseUserGithub.Item::class], version = 1)
abstract class FavDb : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun FavDao(): FavDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: FavDb? = null
        @JvmStatic
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): FavDb {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(FavDb::class.java) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,
                        FavDb::class.java, "fav_database")
                        .allowMainThreadQueries() /* ADDDED FOR INITIAL DEBUG */
                        .build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE as FavDb
        }
    }
}
```

- **`ResponseUserGithub`** remains **unchanged**

When the App is first run using the above, then:-

The log includes

:-

```
2023-09-29 09:38:47.689 D/ITEMINFO_STG001: Item avatarURL is avatarURL004 Login is loginD ID is -99
2023-09-29 09:38:47.690 D/ITEMINFO_STG001: Item avatarURL is avatarURL001 Login is loginA ID is 0
2023-09-29 09:38:47.690 D/ITEMINFO_STG001: Item avatarURL is avatarURL002 Login is loginB ID is 1
2023-09-29 09:38:47.690 D/ITEMINFO_STG001: Item avatarURL is avatarURL003 Login is loginC ID is 2

2023-09-29 09:38:47.694 D/ITEMINFO_STG002_DLT1: Item avatarURL is avatarURL004 Login is loginD ID is -99
2023-09-29 09:38:47.694 D/ITEMINFO_STG002_DLT1: Item avatarURL is avatarURL001 Login is loginA ID is 0
2023-09-29 09:38:47.694 D/ITEMINFO_STG002_DLT1: Item avatarURL is avatarURL003 Login is loginC ID is 2
```

- So clearly the 4 rows have been added (STG001), and
- A row has been deleted so STG002 displays 3 rows (and DLT is followed by 1 the returned result from the `@Dalete` i.e. the number of affected(deleted) rows).

  - You may ask why did a row get deleted when the **Item** to be deleted (constructed using `"not an avatarURL????",1,"not a loginZ"`) was not an **Item** that was added. The answer is that an `@Delete` (like an `@Update`) uses the primary key to determine the affected row. For an `@Delete` the other fields are irrelevant, for an update the other fields will be the values that are applied by the update.

Using App Inspection then:-

[image]

Which further confirms that the Inserts and Deletes do work and that the issue is not due to the database/Room code but with the UI code.

**This answer is only intended to assist with reducing the scope of the issue to the UI code and thus eliminating issues with the Room code**.

> there is an error in Log Cat that i don't understand what is the meaning is that, here is the error :

Errors in the Logcat, often occur, but do not result in the App crashing. As you, after running the App, used App Inspection (and assuming that it did not issue a message that it could not open the database) then it is more than likely that the App has not crashed/stopped. If it showed the database components then the App did not crash and the error messages (which App Inspection does frequently generate) may well be App Inspection doing it's work.

e.g. consider the following which is the log from when App Inspection was started:-

```
2023-09-29 10:14:38.307 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"
2023-09-29 10:14:38.314 5453-5560/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting D/StudioTransport: Receiving kDaemonConnectRequest, receive_fd=55 current_fd_=-1
2023-09-29 10:14:38.314 5453-5560/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Create gRPC channel on fd-based target 'unix:&55'
2023-09-29 10:14:38.293 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinserting: type=1400 audit(0.0:2551): avc: denied { read } for name="u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=6282 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c229,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:serialno_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
2023-09-29 10:14:38.326 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent command stream started.
2023-09-29 10:14:38.331 5453-5559/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: JNIEnv not attached
2023-09-29 10:14:38.341 5453-5559/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Memory control stream started.
2023-09-29 10:14:38.566 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobService
2023-09-29 10:14:38.743 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager
2023-09-29 10:14:38.921 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/location/LocationManager
2023-09-29 10:14:39.094 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/IntentService
2023-09-29 10:14:39.265 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobServiceEngine$JobHandler
2023-09-29 10:14:39.466 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/location/LocationManager$ListenerTransport
2023-09-29 10:14:39.641 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/JobSchedulerImpl
2023-09-29 10:14:39.816 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager$ListenerWrapper
2023-09-29 10:14:39.985 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager
2023-09-29 10:14:40.152 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
2023-09-29 10:14:40.322 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2023-09-29 10:14:40.496 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/Debug
2023-09-29 10:14:40.678 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/ActivityThread
2023-09-29 10:14:40.851 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/Instrumentation
2023-09-29 10:14:40.936 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
2023-09-29 10:14:40.950 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: androidx/fragment/app/Fragment
2023-09-29 10:14:40.956 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:40.956 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting I/chatty: uid=10741(a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting) identical 14 lines
2023-09-29 10:14:40.957 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:40.966 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Class android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-09-29 10:14:40.966 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
2023-09-29 10:14:40.966 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: and incorrect proguard optimizations.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.015 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Profiler initialization complete on agent.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.015 5453-5559/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Transport agent connected to daemon.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.019 5453-5573/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
2023-09-29 10:14:41.034 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:23 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.034 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: JNIEnv not attached
2023-09-29 10:14:41.143 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:24 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.257 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:25 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.495 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:26 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.501 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:27 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.503 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:28 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.493 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting: type=1400 audit(0.0:2552): avc: denied { write } for comm=656374696F6E207072696D6172795D name="perfd" dev="dm-1" ino=36658 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c229,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2023-09-29 10:14:41.503 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting I/chatty: uid=10741(a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting) identical 4 lines
2023-09-29 10:14:41.503 5453-5453/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting: type=1400 audit(0.0:2557): avc: denied { write } for comm=656374696F6E207072696D6172795D name="perfd" dev="dm-1" ino=36658 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c229,c258,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:shell_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2023-09-29 10:14:41.610 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:29 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.615 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:30 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.688 5453-5592/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
2023-09-29 10:14:41.703 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:31 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.803 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:32 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:41.985 5453-5592/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:41.998 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager
2023-09-29 10:14:42.099 5453-5590/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
2023-09-29 10:14:42.264 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager
2023-09-29 10:14:42.307 5453-5592/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:42.495 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/AlarmManager
2023-09-29 10:14:42.502 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: FAILURE TO RETRANFORM Modification of Interface classes is currently not supported
2023-09-29 10:14:42.502 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 79(JVMTI_ERROR_UNMODIFIABLE_CLASS) 
2023-09-29 10:14:42.703 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2023-09-29 10:14:42.967 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2023-09-29 10:14:43.140 5453-5592/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:43.155 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2023-09-29 10:14:43.434 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2023-09-29 10:14:43.699 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting I/chatty: uid=10741(a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting) ection primary] identical 1 line
2023-09-29 10:14:43.918 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/PendingIntent
2023-09-29 10:14:44.220 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/Instrumentation
2023-09-29 10:14:44.534 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/Instrumentation
2023-09-29 10:14:44.714 5453-5592/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:44.765 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/IntentService
2023-09-29 10:14:44.958 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/ActivityThread
2023-09-29 10:14:45.258 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
2023-09-29 10:14:45.342 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:33 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:45.437 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:34 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:45.458 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager
2023-09-29 10:14:45.530 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:35 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:45.631 5453-5564/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioTransport: Agent handling command (id:36 type:APP_INSPECTION) for pid:5453.
2023-09-29 10:14:45.634 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager
2023-09-29 10:14:45.808 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
2023-09-29 10:14:45.810 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Class android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-09-29 10:14:45.981 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
2023-09-29 10:14:45.983 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Class android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-09-29 10:14:46.152 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
2023-09-29 10:14:46.154 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Class android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-09-29 10:14:46.319 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/os/PowerManager$WakeLock
2023-09-29 10:14:46.321 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting W/oomnotinsertin: Class android.os.PowerManager$WakeLock failed lock verification and will run slower.
2023-09-29 10:14:46.499 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/JobSchedulerImpl
2023-09-29 10:14:46.674 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/JobSchedulerImpl
2023-09-29 10:14:46.851 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobServiceEngine$JobHandler
2023-09-29 10:14:47.028 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobServiceEngine$JobHandler
2023-09-29 10:14:47.201 5453-5591/a.a.so77195407kotlinroomnotinserting V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: android/app/job/JobService
```

if you hunt through the above you will see that there are 2 Error messages but they do not affect the App's data nor App Inspection being able to inspect the Database. They are just something you learn to generally ignore (considering other aspects, such as the App being detached).

Comment: Hi Mike thank you so much for the answer and the solution, I found the error, apparently it was due to an error in the UI as you told me before, the error was in the logic that I created, now everything runs smoothly, thank you

Comment: @Dzy Good to hear, well done.

Answer (score -1):

That error message looks like an issue with the emulator.
Could you try a different emulator or running the app on a physical device just to confirm?

Refer [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/app-crashes-at-specific-time-maybe-due-to-memtrack/29329) for a similar issue like yours that was solved by using a different emulator.